# Use kernel driver for Intel graphics

Tags: 14.04, i915

I'm trying to figure out how to force my gfx card to use i915 kernel driver. My card according to lspci is `Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)`.

The reason I want this is because all videos play in slow motion. I asked around and was told to look at `lspci -k` output. It says VGA is not using any kernel drivers. I booted my computer off LiveCD, looked at `lspci -k` output and saw the line `Kernel driver in use: i915`, so that is why I want to force it. `lsmod` on LiveCD lists `i915` with a 4 next to it, whereas there is a 0 next to it on the installed system. I am on 14.04 at the moment, and this problem with the installation of 14.04. Please help me.

```
$ lspci -k
Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) 
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20e4 

$ lsmod | grep i915: 
i915 705396 0 
i2c_algo_bit 13197 1 i915 
drm_kms_helper 46907 1 i915 
video 18903 1 i915 
drm 243792 2 i915
drm_kms_helper
```

These are on the installed system.

Comment: Please _show_ the output of the commands instead of describing it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. You can then ping the user who asked for the information by leaving a comment and including a `@` before their username. For example, to ping me: `@terdon`.

Comment: @terdon I reformatted my post.

Comment: Thanks. Your post is still confusing though. When you say "Live system", do you mean the _installed_ system or the Live CD one? I assume you mean _installed_ and have edited accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I mean _installed_, sorry. Also, thanks for editing.

Comment: Looks like i915 is in use, in other words, no need to force anything.

Comment: But all my videos play in slow motion.

Comment: Also, neither `lspci -k` output nor `lshw -c display` output show a driver in use.

Comment: @Kartagis; If still want to know what going on, Try `modinfo i915` for both live & installed system. It is possible that you are using same driver but with referent loading parameters. Hopefully if you found some please edit question so it will be more clear.

Comment: @Sneetsher as I said in my own answer, I was helped IRC about it. Turns out, I had forgotten a `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub`. I took that out and did an `update-grub`. voilá! Thanks for the reply though-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TJ- on IRC made me realise I had put a `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub`. I removed that and did a `sudo update-grub`, voila!